# Is it possible to count character in TYPO3 RTE?

Tags: typo3, rte

Is there a way to count the number of character in the RTE ?
By default, it count the number of words but can we change that ?

I've read all the docs and haven't find anything.

[image: RTE capture]

Answer (score 0):

The original version of [HTMLArea](http://htmlarea.sourceforge.net/) does not support this feature. TYPO3 comes with a modified version of HTMLArea, where the [word count feature](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/23780) has been implemented for some years ago.

I had a look into the source code of TYPO3s RTE HTMLArea and the word count is hardcoded and not configurable.

A possibility to add the char count is to modify the shipped version of HTMLArea.

Open the file `\typo3\sysext\rtehtmlarea\htmlarea\htmlarea.js` and replace the function `updateWordCount` with the following.

```
updateWordCount: function() {
    var wordCount = 0;
    if (this.getEditor().getMode() == 'wysiwyg') {
            // Get the html content
        var text = this.getEditor().getHTML();
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
                // Replace html tags with spaces
            text = text.replace(HTMLArea.RE_htmlTag, ' ');
                // Replace html space entities
            text = text.replace(/&nbsp;|&#160;/gi, ' ');
                // Remove numbers and punctuation
            text = text.replace(HTMLArea.RE_numberOrPunctuation, '');
                // Get the number of word
            wordCount = text.length;
        }
    }
        // Update the word count of the status bar
    this.statusBarWordCount.dom.innerHTML = wordCount + '&nbsp;' + ( wordCount == 1 ? 'char' : 'chars');
},
```

Please note, that this is a quick and dirty solution which does not repect translation of the words "char" and "chars".

If you modify `htmlarea.js`, keep in mind that you manually have to update your changes after each TYPO3 core update.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TYPO3 7 you have to use this modifed script from the previos answer:

```
updateWordCount: function() {
var wordCount = 0;
if (this.getEditor().getMode() == 'wysiwyg') {
        // Get the html content
    var text = this.getEditor().getHTML();
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(text)) {
            // Replace html tags with spaces
        text = text.replace(HTMLArea.RE_htmlTag, ' ');
            // Replace html space entities
        text = text.replace(/&nbsp;|&#160;/gi, ' ');
            // Remove numbers and punctuation
        text = text.replace(HTMLArea.RE_numberOrPunctuation, '');
            // Get the number of word
        wordCount = text.length;
    }
}
    // Update the word count of the status bar
this.statusBarWordCount.innerHTML = wordCount + '&nbsp;' + ( wordCount == 1 ? 'char' : 'chars');
},
```

i had to remove .dom from the following line:

```
this.statusBarWordCount.dom.innerHTML
```